# Mongoid get multiple data with only single query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

When my page load, it render the Highcharts data (like `[1,2,5,10,40]` )

**controller**

```
@server = Server.find(params[:id])
@statuses = @server.statuses.where(:created_at => 1.days.ago..Time.now)
@statuses.each do |status|
    if status.players.nil?
        @chartData << 0
    else
        @chartData << status.players
    end
end
```

**view**

`... ,"data": <%=chartData.to_a%> ...`

But in this code, I reached the performance issue.

- get first data
- get second data
- get third data
- get fourth data
- **...**

Every page load, it get all of the `@statuses` with multiple query. (not single query) and the page get slow down.

Can I get all of the data using only **single** query like MySQL (`SELECT * FROM sometable`)?

**added**

Sorry I confused some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
@statuses = Server.includes(:statuses).where(:created_at => 1.days.ago..Time.now)
 @statuses.each do |status|
   if status.players.nil?
     @chartData << 0
   else
     @chartData << status.players
  end
end
```